# trying to stop multiple event triggers on android tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, tablet, browser-detection

I'm making a website that will be displayed on a desktop/laptop and a tablet. The problem is that my touch events trigger both mouse and touch events, so the functions that use events like `swipe` are called twice. I've tried to solve the problem by detecting the device and then unbinding mouse events. But my approach has not stopped the mouse/touch functions from being triggered twice.

Here is my code:

```
//Device Detection
    (function () {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        var isDevice = agent.match(/android/i);

        if (isDevice == 'android') {
            alert(isDevice);    

            $('*').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave mousedown mouseup mousemove');
        }
    })();
```

This function is placed at the end of my `.js` document. I tried to be cautious and unbinded every mouse event I could think of, but it has not worked. Please help.

(Note: this thread's approach has not been helpful either: [Click event called twice on touchend in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503453/click-event-called-twice-on-touchend-in-ipad))

Comment: Does this question still need an answer or has it been solved? If the first, I would have some questions beforehand.

Comment: Still needs an answer. what are your questions?

Comment: I landed on this thread because of the `browser-detection` tag, and I recently found out how to detect-distinguish between tablets and non-tablets, iOS and Android, and the several browsers on Android. But now that I re-read your question, and especially the non-helpful thread you linked to, it has become clear to me this is not my expertise. Sorry if I gave you false hope!