# Is there a way that a touch start event will not trigger the click event?

Tags: javascript, events, touch, mouse

When a visitor **clicks** on an image the `click` event will be triggered. However when someone touches the image, that same `click` event will be triggered, even if a `touchstart` event is available as well.

I like a different behavior for an actual click (mouse) event and a touch event. The strange thing is, even a `mouseup` event is triggered when used on a smartphone. Is there anyway you can separate the mouse from the touch events?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Did the trick, hope this helps people!

Comment: This won't work if you're just adding `event.preventDefault()` to the `touchstart` callback. At least not on links in iOS 8.4 Safari. You'd have to add it to the `click` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

you can normalize an event..

See my answer to this question:

[Click event called twice on touchend in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503453/click-event-called-twice-on-touchend-in-ipad/8505370#8505370)

You can also look in the jQuery mobile source code to find inspiration: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js  Start at line 982

```
/* 
* "events" plugin - Handles events
*/

(function( $, window, undefined ) {

// add new event shortcuts
$.each( ( "touchstart touchmove touchend orientationchange throttledresize " +
                    "tap taphold swipe swipeleft swiperight scrollstart scrollstop" ).split( " " ), function( i, name ) {

    $.fn[ name ] = function( fn ) {
        return fn ? this.bind( name, fn ) : this.trigger( name );
    };

    $.attrFn[ name ] = true;
});
....
```

Look at the tap event: (line 1049)

```
$.event.special.tap = {
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. The only thing is, now you are targeting 'special devices specifically' in this case the iPhone. I rather want all devices that support touchstart to treat click and touchstart different. I wish there was a simple var you could set to disable.

Answer (score -1):

It is a complex way to prevent click after touchstart. The click which propagates after touchstart is called ghost click.

Google has implemented a solution. Here you go..

http://code.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons.html#ghost