# jQuery 1.9.1 $.event.handle.apply alternative

Tags: jquery, upgrade

I recently updated one of my project to jQuery 1.9.1, and I can no longer use `$.event.handle.apply()` method. I've searched and found, that I can place jquery.migrate.js. I just want to confirm if there is any other option? My google-fu is failing here...

--EDIT-- Here is the code (not mine... copied from the plugin) that is causing the issue...

```
// Event handler function
function mouseWheelHandler(event)
{
    var sentEvent = event || window.event,
        orgEvent = sentEvent.originalEvent || sentEvent,
        args = [].slice.call( arguments, 1 ),
        delta = 0,
        deltaX = 0,
        deltaY = 0;
        event = $.event.fix(orgEvent);
        event.type = "mousewheel";

    // Old school scrollwheel delta
    if ( orgEvent.wheelDelta ) { delta = orgEvent.wheelDelta/120; }
    if ( orgEvent.detail     ) { delta = -orgEvent.detail/3; }

    // New school multidimensional scroll (touchpads) deltas
    deltaY = delta;

    // Gecko
    if ( orgEvent.axis !== undefined && orgEvent.axis === orgEvent.HORIZONTAL_AXIS ) {
        deltaY = 0;
        deltaX = -1*delta;
    }

    // Webkit
    if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaY !== undefined ) { deltaY = orgEvent.wheelDeltaY/120; }
    if ( orgEvent.wheelDeltaX !== undefined ) { deltaX = -1*orgEvent.wheelDeltaX/120; }

    // Add event and delta to the front of the arguments
    args.unshift(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY);

    return $.event.handle.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you were using something undocumented and internal, and it changed. We might be able to help you if you said what it was you wanted to do (as we won't all be familiar with the undocumented and internal thing you used to use).

Comment: Perhaps you want `$().trigger`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder .. Thanks for reply... Please have a look at the edits..

Comment: @JanDvorak.. $().trigger is causing error  "TypeError: type.indexOf is not a function" at line 2922 (ucompressed jquery.js)..

Answer (score 10):

or you can try:

> $.event.**dispatch**.call( obj, event );

Comment: I found this in jQuery 1.8.3: `jQuery.event.handle = jQuery.event.dispatch;`

Answer (score 6):

I found this topic while looking for a solution for Infinite Scroll which does not work with jQuery 1.9.* and causes the same error as from the original post.

JQNinja's comment provided a suitable solution: changing the single instance of `$.event.handle.apply` to `$.event.dispatch.apply` in the plugin fixes Infinite Scroll. I am assuming it will also fix the original poster's problem.

I understand that modifying a plugin is not ideal, but since it is no longer maintained at the time of writing, I probably don't have to concern myself with updates -- and let's assume that, should maintenance be resumed, this problem will be fixed as well!

Comment: Thanks for answering... But I am no longer working on this... so I can not test whether it works... I don't know if I should leave this question as it is, or mark it as closed anyway?!!

Comment: tried this in another plugin - did the trick there too. I only wish I knew what it meant :-)

Comment: Confirmed swapping dispatch for handle works with this mousewheel mod. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you will see [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11028) this plugin wasn't longer developped. But it the end of this discussion you have a way to solve some problem :

On line 642 of the plugin js file I have this:

```
event.type = 'lastclick';
$.event.handle.apply(Me, [event,clicks])
```

I just changed those two to this:

```
event.type = 'lastclick';
event.isPropagationStopped = function() { return false };
$.event.handle.apply(Me, [event,clicks])
```

So, I just reseted the `isPropagationStopped` and sudently it started working fine!

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Did you test this approach in 1.9.1?

Comment: not yet but it's in test. and for me the $().trigger is a better approach

Comment: This is old solution. I am asking for JQuery 1.9.1 and $.event.handle.apply is removed according to jquers docs.

Answer (score 0):

i Found solution here , i test it and it work fine
[Get mouse wheel events in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189840/get-mouse-wheel-events-in-jquery/15629039#15629039)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
            $(this).text('scrolling up !');
        }
        else{
           $(this).text('scrolling down !');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

change this line:

> return $.event.handle.apply(this, args);

to:

> return **jQuery**.event.handle.apply(this, args);