# iOS8 Safari -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; issue

Tags: html, ios, css

So we are building this web app for a client which worked perfectly on iOS7 in Safari. But when we checked the app out in iOS8 it had a some huge bugs.

- If a user opens the sidebar and closes it, content that is in a `<section style="overlay-y: scroll;"></section>` disappears ( the overlaid part ).
- Some buttons stopped working for any reason. ( `<a href="">Lala</a>` )

When we remove `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` from the container ( the div that holds all the content ) everything works flawlessly like it used to...

Any ideas on what it might be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iframe scrolling iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046373/iframe-scrolling-ios-8)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm having this same issue! So far I can't find a true solution, but there is a less-than-ideal workaround:

Assuming #container has the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` property set, this jQuery should help you out:

```
$('#container').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling','auto');
```

Or for javascript (untested):

```
document.getElementById('container').style.webkitOverflowScrolling = 'auto';
```

This will disable the smooth roulette-style scrolling on the page. So it's not ideal, but your page should scroll correctly now.

## **Edit:**

Some further research led to our discovery of a more hacky way to resolve this while keeping the smooth touch scrolling working. Assuming you have `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` somewhere in the css, you can "toggle" it within your JS. I'm not sure what you have that shows/hides the menu, but hopefully you can utilize this.

```
function toggleMenu(){
    $('#container').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling','auto');

    //...Existing code

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#container').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling','touch');
    },500);
}
```

This didn't work for me without the setTimeout. Hope this can help you or someone else out.

Comment: Good to hear. Hopefully Apple and/or the webkit people know about this issue.

Comment: For me that option does not work. 
I wanna try to avoid and code the fix with js. The content of my container get's a similar behaviour when its parent elements have position absolute or relative. Without that positioning the smooth scrolling works fine.

Will appreciate that this would be discuss further. :)

Comment: So far I've stuck with this solution, and haven't tried anything using just css. Someone elsewhere mentioned using `transform3d(0,0,0)` but that didn't work for me. You might want to give that a try. Sorry I couldn't be more help. This is hopefully a temporary fix until Apple resolves the problem themselves.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, saved my bacon!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problems in iOS8 that all my buttons binded to click event are not working properly. In general we will have 300 ms delayed but at some points i will need to press more than couple of times to get it triggered.

So i also found this solution which works on mine. Adding touchend with click.

```
button.on('click touchend', function(event) {
  // this fires twice on touch devices
});
```

You can see the forum they discussed here.

[JavaScript touchend versus click dilemma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572070/javascript-touchend-versus-click-dilemma)

I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your sidebar animated with CSS animations by any chance?

I had the same bug in a Cordova web app. After some experimenting, I found that the problem was caused by parent `<div>` (the sidebar) that was being animated through css animations and had the property `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Removing this property solved the issue and restored the expected `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` behavior

Answer (score -1):

My answer is:

```
$('#container').css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling','auto');
```

Previous solution didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('container').style.webkitOverflowScrolling = 'auto';
```